# MySql : Updating all except the first row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I went through the previous answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584194/how-to-update-all-rows-except-one-row-out-of-many-satisfying-the-given-condition), but it gives me the following error : `You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause`.

I have a table with say 3 columns (id -> auto increment primary id) :

> id, roll_no and attendance

And for selected roll numbers having many entries each, `except the first entry` I want to update all entry `attendance` field as `P`.

The query which I wrote is following :

```
UPDATE tbl_class_attendance 
   set attendance = 'P' 
 where id NOT IN 
   (Select min(id) 
      from tbl_class_attendance 
     WHERE roll_no IN ('25', '45', '55') 
     GROUP 
       BY roll_no;
```

But it gives me the above error.
I also went through other answers asking to use two select queries but there the answer I didn't find completely easy to understand as well as difficulty in executing for my selected list of roll numbers.

So, is there a way to update?

EDIT : Answer given below

Comment: And incidentally, this query wouldn't give that error

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: @Sergiu The answer doesn't work with Group by in nested select

Comment: Use multiple-table UPDATE syntax - the subquery must be in UPDATE clause tables list, not in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Strawberry It is giving the error `You can't specify target table 'table_name' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @Akina But my inner query is giving the result for my Where clause

Comment: You cannot use the subquery in WHERE when it uses the table to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by following :

```
Update table SET a=value WHERE x IN
          (Select * from (select x from table where condition) as t)
```

Credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43610081/6366458

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE tbl_class_attendance t1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT t2.roll_no, MIN(t2.id) id
            FROM tbl_class_attendance t2
            WHERE t2.roll_no IN ('25', '45', '55') 
            GROUP BY t2.roll_no ) t3 USING (roll_no, id)
SET t1.attendance = 'P' 
WHERE t3.id IS NULL;
```